# How to send a message to facebook inbox using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

How to send message to facebook user Inbox using ASP.NET 3.5 and C#?
I am able to post the messages on walls using `fbAPI.Stream.Publish()` but i need to send message to inbox need to be personal.
Please guide me.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/

Answer (score 3):

facebook does not allow applications to send personal messages to users