# Php graph api to send private messages to friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to send private messages to facebook friends by using php graph api as we can post messages on friends walls using graph api.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked and answered **many times** in stackoverflow.

[how send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

[Send private messages to friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-messages-to-friends)

[Sending private messages through Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363515/sending-private-messages-through-facebook-api)

And more...

try to search before ask your question for the text time.