# fb php api - move message from "other" to inbox when mailing to @facebook adress

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

there are @facebook emails for normal users (not for fan pages asaik). 
I am sending a private message to this @facebook email of a user from a normal email address but the message always gets to the "other" folder of facebook. This is logical, since otherwise there would be a lot of spam. If the user goes to the "other" Folder and moves the message to the inbox, then this email-address becomes "known". So the next email will land in his inbox folder.

I would like to make this process (marking the email-address as known) using the php api - is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

regards - Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously that is surely not possible, because you would be allowed to avoid the useful spam detection that way. Also, the @facebook.com addresses are deprecated:

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-26332191

For communication between users and pages:

- [Facebook API support for User-Page private messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598369/facebook-api-support-for-user-page-private-messages)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations

Comment: I see, yeah this sounds pretty logical too ... :|  Ok so is there any way a fan page can send messages to the user (if the user accepts this kind of communication of course) ?

Comment: no, a fan page can and should ONLY send messages to a user if he initiates the communication, but there´s the message inbox for that. so a user has to send a private message to a page, then the page can answer. i never did this with the api, but i think it is possible.

Comment: I was searching for that and didn't find anything. The only thing that seems to be possible is reading the messages using the api but not replying

Comment: i included some links for that in the answer, check it out