# Facebook SDK/API getting in touch with page likers / fans

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are looking to develop a Facebook app for a client of ours - this subject seems to be a huge discussion as to what information an app can access.  We just needed to find out for certain what we can and can't do from someone who has maybe been here before.

If you have a page with 10,000 likes, we've pretty much come to the conclusion that Facebook will not let you create an app to allow sending messages to these people who have liked the page - is this correct?  We want a way to communicate with these people!

We saw that there is a way to send a 'notification' via an App (which isn't ideal as we'd have to build the 10,000 users all over again), and wasn't sure whether this had any restrictions either (i.e. whether it is just for games or whether the wording is limited etc).

In a nutshell, does anyone know whether it would be possible to create a Facebook App, which isn't a game, to create a way of messaging the users who have liked a page?  Or at least an App which we can try to turn the page likes into App authorisation and connect with them that way?

Comment: That is not possible. The way you communicate with those people is to post stuff on your page

Comment: To the down-voter, I'm not sure why you down-voted this question, the question is perfectly legitimate, and obviously well researched. Even if the answer is no, this doesn't make the question a bad question

Comment: @George This question shows a basic lack of understanding of how Facebook works, so I downvoted it as "not useful".

Comment: @admdrew I would imagine that his lack of understanding is what lead him to ask the question..

Comment: Basically this is a question about how to create a spam app …

Comment: @George Sure, which could've been answered by personal research.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://www.facebook.com/help/273376269375028

```
You can only send messages to people who've sent a message to your Page
```

Also, check out the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/conversations

```
You can't publish using this edge, you can send replies via the API by using the /{conversation-id}/messages edge.
```

**So, it is possible to post a message to a fan, but only in reply.**

There is more in this thread: [Facebook API support for User-Page private messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598369/facebook-api-support-for-user-page-private-messages)

So the only way (for very good reasons) to get to all likers is to post something on the wall of your Page.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply I appreciate it