# Best way to privately contact/notify a user from a canvas app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-canvas

I have a canvas app that performs operations on behalf of a user. Sometimes these operations fail in the background. What is the best way to notify the user of the failure without sharing it in any way on their wall etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here as there has been no activity and the simple answer is that it's not possible at the moment:

[Sending private messages through Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363515/sending-private-messages-through-facebook-api)

Comment: You could use Notifications though …