# How does the iPhone facebook-app handle private messages?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

In other threads like [Send private messages to friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-messages-to-friends) it says that you can't send private messages to other facebook users via Graph API, which is also what I find out reading the official API.

But the iPhone facebook-app (which uses the Graph API, correct me if that's wrong) supports sending private messages, so I was wondering how they accomplished to do this. Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook's iPhone app, being official, has access to unreleased APIs that normal developers do not.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any further information about these unreleased APIs?

Comment: It's hard enough to find good documentation on Facebook's **released** APIs. Heh.