# How to send private messages in Facebook inbox

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Api - send messages to friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-messages-to-friends)

I wanted to post a private messages from my Facebook APP but I have no Idea. 
How to  send private messages in Facebook inbox through Graph API ?

Comment: Possibly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-messages-to-friends

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no current API for sending Facebook messages.

Comment: i would say fortunately.