# Is it possible to make a continuously counting/working calendar with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I started learning programming a few years ago with java (minecraft, anyone?) but I only got to the point of creating tic-tac-toe playable on the console and then stopped.

Now, with codecademy, I have finished the html, css and jQuery courses and now intend to delve into javascript. My plan is to make an app for facebook with a colleague, app which would alert everyone on the class the week before a test. To do this, I would need a working calendar that kept "scanning" the date and once he found that there's something to alert on a certain day, it does.

Is that possible to do with javascript?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767303/facebook-apps-scheduling-a-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, to answer your question, developing the app you've mentioned is not possible only by involving some html/css and javascript. See the more in depth comments posted in the thread I mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, no.
I don't know if I understand your question, but I'll try to answer ;)

1. If you need calendar try [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)
2. You will need something like "Facebook api" to load dates from FB calendar
3. Why just don't try to
   find some function like "notify me 1 week before event" --> possible
   with Google calendar

I'm not very interested in JS, but I think that it's better to scan database, not a website. And what type of app do you want to create? [Faceboom app](https://developers.facebook.com/) or website?

Comment: The asker says he wants to make a facebook app.

Comment: You should use this site [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)