# How to send message on facebook from own site in Php(joomla)

Tags: php, facebook, joomla, facebook-graph-api, joomla1.5

I am importing contacts from facebook in joomla and trying to send message from my site using user email Id , but it is not sending messages.Please Help...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page and improve your question. Your question, as it stands, does not have enough information and is unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send email to the user's friends, that's not possible as answered here:

[Send private messages to friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-messages-to-friends)

Answer (score 0):

You might not have setup the email settings properly on the joomla backend. If this is the problem then you can look at this post to setup Joomla so it can send out emails:

http://www.katcode.com/joomla-setup-smtp-email-capability-using-gmail-smtp/