# Send private message to my friend(s) using my Android application

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an application in which user can share messages with his/her Facebook friends. I am using Facebook API for Android.

I can able to authenticate user, as well as I can get my friend list as a Facebook user and also post message on wall, but I am looking for sending private message to my friends and I didn't get any solution for that, so can any body help me, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-private-messages-to-friends

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to send private messages on the behalf of the user using the graph api.

You should however be able to use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), though I haven't tried it on android, but it should be something like:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", "USER_ID");
params.putString("name", "TITLE HERE");
params.putString("link", "A URL"); // this link param is required

facebook.dialog(context, "send", params, new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
       ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {}
});
```

Another approach you can use is the [Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) with which you can send messages on the behalf of the user, it requires the `xmpp_login` permission and you to implement an xmpp client.

---

## Edit

Since this dialog is not supported yet in android, you have 3 options:

1. Wait for facebook to implement the dialog for android.
2. Try to open the dialog in a browser (the url for that is in the docs) in the mobile device.
3. Ask for the `xmpp_login` and add a xmpp client (i.e.: [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/)) and with that you can implement your own "Send Message" dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. already i used above code but in Send Dialog it says "This Dialog is currently not supported on mobile devices".

Comment: Eh, I was afraid of that (since it's not in the docs), but was worth the try. I edited my answer with more info.

Comment: hi,
u said //Try to open the dialog in a browser (the url for that is in the docs) in the mobile device.// 
which url u r indicating, can u give me the doc link or url link please

Comment: It's right there in the page I linked (`Send Dialog`): `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123050457758183
  &link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html
  &redirect_uri=https://www.bancsabadell.com/cs/Satellite/SabAtl/`

Comment: There is a message that Chat API is depricated on provided Chat API link. Does it means that they don't support Chat API anymore? Or this API moved to Facebook 2.0 API? I couldn't find any description of current version of Chat API.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Android SDK features now the (private) Message Dialog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/message-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessengerUtils to send the message with attachments.

[image]

You can send attachment with following mime types:

[image]

Sample code to send image is like below

```
String mimeType = "image/jpeg";

// contentUri points to the content being shared to Messenger
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
        ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, mimeType)
                .build();

// Sharing from an Activity
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
       this,
       REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
       shareToMessengerParams);
```

[image]

More documentation is on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

Comment: There's nothing on that page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send facebook private message using below code.

```
if (isPackageExisted("com.facebook.orca")) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
        uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, Long.parseLong("Enter user id here"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install facebook messenger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Check Facebook messenger is install or not

```
 public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```