# facebook send message on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I haven't found a Facebook API to send a private message to the logged in user's friend.
I would like to use something like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

But calling this dialog up in a browser on the phone isn't a great user experience.

Is their either an API i can use to send a message to a Facebook friend?
Or are there plans to support the send dialog on Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764381/send-private-message-to-my-friends-using-my-android-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-private-messages-to-friends