# How to get Facebook Friends list in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Facebook friends list in my android application (friend picker not required).I have followed the the procedure describe on [Facebook application development](https://developers.facebook.com)

I have also run the samples , but confused to get the friends list. your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get friend list with this code

```
 String returnString = null;
            JSONObject json_data = null;

            try
            {
                JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/friends"));
                JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);




                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                        Log.i("log_tag","User Name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                                ", user_id: "+json_data.getString("id"));

                                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                };


                flist.setText(returnString);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (FacebookError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I get just name and id , if you want get different things,

Comment: it is another question , and I am not sure it is possible or not , I should search :)

Comment: it is not possible look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764381/send-private-message-to-my-friends-using-my-android-application

Comment: After long search i also found that it is not possible yet

Comment: @ Ersin Gülbahar : m getting blank array .. please helpme

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

```
private static final String LOGTAG = "MainActivity";

private List<GraphUser> tags;

private Button pickFriendsButton;

Button locationtoast;

private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;// 2

private LoginButton fb_loginBtn;// loginbtn

private TextView userName, userName2, userName3, userName4, text;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

// private Button pickFriendsButton;

Button btnlogin;
String Name;
String Id;
String lastname;
String firstname;
String getUsername;
String get_gender;
GraphPlace location;
String profileid;
String birthday;
String get_email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationtoast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.location_button);
    locationtoast.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_view);
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);// 3

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    fb_loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);

    pickFriendsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_friend);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());
    pickFriendsButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
    pickFriendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickPickFriends();
        }

        private void onClickPickFriends() {
            final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

            setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);
            showPickerFragment(fragment);
        }

        private void showPickerFragment(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
            fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    String text = getString(R.string.exception,
                            error.getMessage());
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
        }

        private void setFriendPickerListeners(
                final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
            fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDoneButtonClicked(
                        PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                    onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
                }
            });
        }

        private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();

            String results = "";

            List<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
            tags = selection;
            if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
                ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                    names.add(user.getName());
                }
                results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
            } else {
                results = getString(R.string.no_friends_selected);
            }
            // showAlert("fghjklkbvbn", results);
            showAlert(getString(R.string.you_picked), results);

        }

        private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
        }

    });

    fb_loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {

        // Intent intent = new Intent(this, ValuesShow.class);

        // startActivity(i);

        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());// 4

                userName.setText("Hello , " + user.getName()
                        + "\n you logged In Uaar Alumni ");
                // userName2.setText("frstname"+ user.getFirstName());
                // userName3.setText("address"+user.getBirthday());
                // userName4.setText("texr"+user.getLocation());

                get_email = (String) user.getProperty("email");

                Name = user.getName();
                Id = user.getId();
                lastname = user.getLastName();
                firstname = user.getFirstName();
                getUsername = user.getUsername();
                location = user.getLocation();
                get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");

                // birthday=user.getBirthday();

                // profileid=user.getId();

                // profilePictureView.setProfileId(Id.getId());
                // text.setText(Name + "  \n " + Id + "\n" + firstname +
                // "\n"
                // + lastname + "\n" + getUsername + "\n" + get_gender);
                // profilePicture=user.getId();

            } else {
                userName.setText("You are not logged");
            }
        }
    });

}

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            text.setText("");
            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent i = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    // case R.id.fb_login_button:

    case R.id.location_button:
        i = new Intent(this, LocationGet.class);
        break;

    // i=new Intent (this,Main_menu.class);
    // break;
    case R.id.profile_view:
        i = new Intent(this, ValuesShow.class);
        Log.d(Name, "" + Name);
        i.putExtra("Name", Name);
        i.putExtra("get_gender", get_gender);
        i.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
        i.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
        i.putExtra("Id", Id);
        i.putExtra("birthday", birthday);
        i.putExtra("get_email", get_email);
        // i.putExtra("profileid",profileid);
        break;

    }

    // profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

    // Intent intent = new Intent(this, ValuesShow.class);

    // intent.getBooleanExtra("location", location);
    Log.d(lastname, "" + lastname);
    Log.d(get_gender, "" + get_gender);
    // Log.d(LOGTAG,"Name value name....");

    startActivity(i);
}
}
```