# How to send Facebook message to friend using Facebook ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have my friend's Facebook id and now want to send him a message through my flex based application. 
How to do it?

**Update:**
I logged-in to my facebook profile and want to send message to my all friends by using flex based application.

**Note:**
I have fetched facebook profile id of all friends.

Comment: Applications (thankfully) can't send messages.  That would be a vulnerability for spam...

Comment: nice one. is it not possible? if yes then is their any possibility to do it.

Comment: @RTA - Read the previous comment. No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook recently published the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/), see also https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/31/reach-users-1-1-with-the-notifications-api/. Those can be send to any user, that is using your app already.

Otherwise, a [user-to-user request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#user_to_user) (considered an “invite”, if the recipient is not user of your app yet) would be the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Do a FQL query to find the user's `username` using the Facebook ID (123).

```
SELECT username FROM user WHERE uid = 123
```

FQL user: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Once you have obtained the `username` of the user, you can send an email to `username@facebook.com` and the recipient will receive it as a Facebook message.

Example: [Allowing users of facebook application to communicate somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819080/allowing-users-of-facebook-application-to-communicate-somehow/11885193#11885193)

(The example is using PHP but the idea is the same)

Comment: That could be a violation of Facebook Platform Policies (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), IV. Application Integration Points, 5.: _“Facebook messaging (i.e., email sent to an @facebook.com address) is designed for communication between users, and not a channel for applications to communicate directly with users.”_