# Publish to a friend's wall using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know we can publish something on a friend's wall with this:

```
$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
     'message' => "Your Message", 
     'link'    => 'http://example.com',
     'picture' => '',
     'name'    => 'App Name',
     'description'=> 'App description'
));
```

Just by replacing the $user variable with the user id of your friend.

What i wish is simply to choose among my friends, the user profiles i want to write on using check boxes.

this is something already possible if you want to share a fan page for instance. You choose the persons you send the request to.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Writing to News Feeds *en masse* would probably be considered spam. Consider using the Requests system instead:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: And is it possible to send notifications before the messages are written on the walls ?

Comment: It is, but that's working around the problem, rather than facing it. The feed is not intended to be used in such a way. If you want a user to be able to send a message to multiple users, use the Requests system, not the Feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook's **Multi-Friend-Selector (MFS)**.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/

An edited example taken from the Multi-Friend-Selector documentation

```
function renderMFS() {
 // First get the list of friends for this user with the Graph API
 FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
   var container = document.getElementById('mfs');
   var mfsForm = document.createElement('form');
   mfsForm.id = 'mfsForm';

   // Iterate through the array of friends object and create a checkbox for each one.
   for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(response.data.length, 10); i++) {
     var friendItem = document.createElement('div');
     friendItem.id = 'friend_' + response.data[i].id;
     friendItem.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="friends" value="'
       + response.data[i].id
       + '" />' + response.data[i].name;
       mfsForm.appendChild(friendItem);
     }
     container.appendChild(mfsForm);

     // Extract selected friends' Facebook ID from value property of checked checkboxes

     // Do a for loop to send notification (refer to the link posted below) and publish post to each user's wall
   });
 }
```

> And is it possible to send notifications before the messages are
>   written on the walls?

Yes it is possible when you have the Facebook ID. Refer to my answer in [How to send Facebook message to friend using Facebook ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370122/how-to-send-facebook-message-to-friend-using-facebook-id/12373036#12373036)