# How to create something like iframe website on facebook in 2012 december version of FB?

Tags: facebook

How to create something like iframe website on facebook in 2012 december version of FB?

It was possible when there were tabs. but after they change the layout is it still possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Api - send private messages to friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-private-messages-to-friends)

Comment: Please clarify: Are you wanting to know if you can put facebook.com in an iframe? If so, the answer is no. They block it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to know if you can put facebook.com in an iframe? If so, the answer is no. They block it. – Tommy Crush